# 2GB+ memory allocation

Tags: c#, memory

I need to allocate more than 2GB of memory in one piece.

1. I can't use an array because there is 2GB limit
2. Even if I use .net Framework 4.5 which allows me to alloc more than 2GB, I still don't want to use an array object
3. I need something like `GlobalHAlloc`, but this method has only 32 bit size parameter

Should I use Windows API or something? I know this is hard to do and I know I will leak a lot of memory because I don't have a skill to do this...

But is there something like `GlobalHAlloc` in the .NET framework 4.5 which gives me easy way to allocate memory? I want to do my own class `MemoryBlock`, because I don't like array class.

Comment: Please tell us why you don't like Array?

Comment: What do you want to do with the memory?  Do you just need a collection of bytes?  Is it a collection of complex objects, of so, what is their size?  What do you plan to do with the allocated memory?  Can it be broken up, or does it need to be contiguous?

Comment: Why do you need to allocate such a large chunk of memory..?

Comment: Also, 32bit (FFFFFFFF) == 4GB, no?

Comment: @activwerx Arrays take a signed int, and don't use the negative range, so the max items in an array is 2^31, not 2^32

Comment: 32 or 64bit Operating System?

Comment: if you are looking to use UnManaged Memory Stream Class here is a link for you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.unmanagedmemorystream%28VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: 64 bit OS. I need this memory to load huge sound files, and do some operations on it. And I dont wanna do a class which divide memory in 2GB pieces. I dont like array because I need to make some extra methods anyway, so new pure class is better for me.

Comment: SpankyJ via MSDN has a blog posting on this [BigArray<T>, getting around the 2GB array size limit](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshwil/archive/2005/08/10/450202.aspx)

Comment: @Servy, what do you mean, "Arrays take a signed int, and don't use the negative range"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a number of methods to get a larger block of memory.

- `AllocHGlobal` in fact takes an `IntPtr` which is a 64 bit sized value on 64 bit.
- Call the native function `HeapAlloc`. Again, it takes a pointer sized parameter.
- Call the native function `CoTaskMemAlloc function` which also takes a pointer sized parameter.

Since you state that `AllocHGlobal` only takes a 32 bit parameter, then it would appear that your process is 32 bit. And that's the real problem. In a 32 bit process you cannot allocate more than 4GB (total). And that limit is imposed by the size of your pointers. As a further limit, in a 32 bit OS, a process cannot allocate more than 2GB (total).

So, I suggest that you need to switch to a 64 bit process to solve your problem.

Comment: +1. Side note: I don't think "on 32 bits you simply cannot allocate more than 2GB" is completely true - one should theoretically be able to get up to full 4GB is 32 bit process running on x64 version of Windows, and up to 3GB if /3GB flag set for 32 bit versions. In practice maximum size is much smaller due to address space fragmentation...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I did actually know that, but thanks for adding the comment. I didn't really want to get into `LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE` and `/3GB`!!

Comment: Thanks, I have 64 bit OS, didn't know IntPtr is platform depend. I have no skills with memory management, so you recommend me AllocHGlobal? Can I do something wrong with this? Or it's just Alloc and Free?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you will do with this buffer once you allocate it. `UnmanagedMemoryStream` does look like a good option. The fact that you have 64 bit OS is not the key factor. Is your process 64 bit too? Or does it target x86?

Comment: 64 bit. (x64) that memory stream has 32 bit offset in read method?

Comment: "AllocHGlobal in fact takes an IntPtr which is a 64 bit sized value on 64 bit." ::  IntPtr -> pointer to the specified number of bytes. So how to alloc 4GB memory? I dont understand.

Comment: IntPtr can represent a pointer. Or you can view it as an integer type. Cast a long to IntPtr, and there's your size parameter.

Comment: In case that is not clear, you write `IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((IntPtr)size);` where `size` is a `long`, i.e. a 64 bit integer.